# Hibernate fails to read DTD intermittently

Tags: hibernate

We have recently upgraded to 4.1.7 and are experiencing issue time to time (very intermittently) on initializing SessionFactory because of unable to read DTD remotely.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()). buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

If we switch to referencing locally, all works well.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration
    PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

To

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

We don't this this is due to network. We are able to reference all other schema references when this one fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Hibernate 4x/5x prefers 
http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd

over

http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd